# HC-06 bluetooth module have interference

Tags: bluetooth, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, hc-05

my HC-06 have interference. I just have plugged it to my testing board and provided 5V. then paired it to my PC and used bluetooth serial terminal to communicate with it. everything is fine until I plug a wire to connect the TX/RX to my programming board. once TX is plugged in, the serial client on my PC start receiving random data. I have removed the wire from the board and it stopped. when I push the testing board with my finger near to the TX section, it start sending again. Do you have a suggestion ? it acts like I'm an antenna.

I discovered this after 2 hours of trying to communicate with it with raspberry pi pico to just make a LED ON/OFF. the program was simple, just send letter ( a ) to have led on and letter ( b ) to have led off, the thing is when I print what my UART is receiving, its a lot of random data instead of just ( a/b ).
By the way, I have 2 bluetooth HC-06 modules and both are acting same

I want to know why I'm getting random data from my HC-06

Comment: This sounds like an [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) question about how to wire the module up, not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure your grounds are tied together between your boards. This is the most likely problem if you're getting "antenna" effects. Something probably isn't grounded correctly.
- Make sure that you're driving your Tx/Rx lines at 3.3V, not 5V

  - I will assume that your board takes 5V for Vcc, since that is common, but remember that the HC-06 itself is 3.3V
  - If you have 5V logic, you can use a [voltage divider resistors](https://components101.com/wireless/hc-06-bluetooth-module-pinout-datasheet) on the Rx line to get it to 3.3V.
- Probably not related, since the symptoms would be a bit different, but make sure your baud rate is set correctly on your other board (9600)

Comment: Hc-06 module voltage is between 3.6 and 6v. I have HW-131 module plugged to 12v2amps supply. HW-131 module provide 5v and 3.3v. I tried to power the HC-06 module with 3.3 and it didn't worked. Actually im not using my raspberry, i just gave 5v power to the module and connected to it using pc bluetooth serial. Once i put my finger near to the module, i start receiving random data. I do understand that it could be a ground issue, but how to ground it? Actually im not using any programming board, so the HC-06 should not receive and transmit anything. Right?

Comment: I have grounded the RXD as shown on the link provided and still getting same random data.

Comment: I assume you've connected pin 3 to ground, and that it's the same ground as your voltage splitter. I'm now I little confused about what your Tx and Rx and tied to. Are you saying they're not connected to anything? (If they're floating, then I could expect some random data.)